# 301 Redirect from Tumblr Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have an old Tumblr blog where I am trying to redirect my old paths to my new website URL. On my old blog, I used a non-www domain name, example.com and now on my new site I am using a www domain name and redirecting all visits to non-www domain name, www.example.com. I have followed the `.htaccess` documentation and believe that my setup is correct, but I get a `404` error. Could this be a result of changing from a non-www to www and that I'm not making a reference to that change in my htaccess file?

Here is an example error: `Cannot GET /post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues`

Here is my file (Could the non-www reference being throwing this off?):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues http://example.com/blog/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues

Redirect 301 /post/96013172504/basic-seo-checklist http://example.com/blog/basic-seo-checklist
```

Comment: If you enter `http://domain.com/post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues` in browser what error do you get?

Comment: Redirect to `http://www.domain.com/post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues` and then an error `Cannot GET /post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues`